# ActiveRecord transaction not rolling back on failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, transactions

I am trying to use an `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` to ensure that a `Customer`, `CustomerAccount` and `StockNotification` all get created at once, or **none gets created at all if one of them fails**

Here is my transaction 
*stock_notification.rb:*

```
  validates_presence_of :email

  def self.make parameters
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      shop_id = ProductVariant.find(parameters[:product_variant_id]).shop_id
      parameters[:customer_account_id] = CustomerAccount.find_or_make!(parameters[:email], shop_id).id
      @stock_notification = StockNotification.create(parameters) # reference A
    end
    @stock_notification
  end
```

You might need this as well 
*customer_account.rb:*

```
  def self.find_or_make! email, shop_id
    customer = Customer.where(email: email).first_or_create!
    CustomerAccount.where(shop_id: shop_id, customer_id: customer.id).first_or_create!
  end
```

If I call `StockNotification.make` with a blank email, the `create` fails (reference A) and no stock notification is created, but the problem is that a `Customer`/`CustomerAccount` is still being created.

So the `transaction` is not doing it's job at all, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Transaction will fail if an exception is raised. You should use not `create`, but `create!` that will do that in case of failure. [See here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).

Comment: But that kills the response, I want to be able to return to the customer with an error message

Comment: `rescue` the error and add an error message? Perhaps this can be structured better...

Comment: Yes that is the solution that I've decided to use. Thanks